# Date.parseExact doesn't give accurate result

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datejs

I am consuming "date.js" and "en-GB.js" libraries from [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

Following command gives a not null result indicating its a valid date, but it isn't actually.

```
Date.parseExact('01/13/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `M` or `MM`

```
Date.parseExact('01/13/2013', 'd/M/yyyy')
```

Lowercase `m` is 'minutes', and since a month wasn't specified in your format string, the library defaulted to use the current month.

Comment: so this completely different from JQuery date picker format 'dd/mm/yyyy' which is a British date format.

Comment: @Nirman Yeah, jQuery datepicker is precise down to the day; since this library wants to be precise down to the second, it needs to be able to have a name to address 'minutes', and only 'm' seems to make sense. It is unintuitive if you're only using it for dates and not time though, since 'day' and 'year' are both lowercase `d` and `y`. You might consider taking a look at Moment.js, which is more consistent in this area and currently seems to be more popular http://momentjs.com/